# Organizing REST webservice

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm trying to structure a REST webservice but I don't know the correct way of returning the results. Could you please give me some hints?

```
/countries/{id_country}/cities/{id_cities}/categories/
```

- Option 1:

Resource link and some parts of the resource description

```
[ { "id": 1,
    "name": "cine",
    "url": "http://domain/countries/1/cities/1/categories/1"
  },
  { "id": 2,
    "name": "restaurante",
    "url": "http://domain/countries/1/cities/1/categories/2"
  }
]
```

- Option 2

Resources link

```
[ { "url": "http://domain/countries/1/universities/1/categories/1" },
  { "url": "http://domain/countries/1/universities/1/categories/2" },
]
```

- Option 3

Resources description

```
[ { "id": 1,
    "name": "cine",
    "description": "text text",
    "url": "http://domain/countries/1/cities/1/categories/1" },
  { "id": 2,
    "name": "restaurante",
    "description": "text text",
    "url": "http://domain/countries/1/cities/1/categories/2" }
]
```

Comment: It depends entirely on what your clients need. I don't see how anybody can tell you what is correct to return.

Comment: +1 to Eric. That said, you should aim to have no more than one url-parameter. This rule of thumb should help you (a bit) to structure your end-points.

Comment: @alfasin what do you mean by one url-parameter? You mean only countries/id  cities/id   categories/id?  Then I would need to use something like categories/id?city=idcity

Comment: No, I meant a parameter which is part of the url, for example `/countries/{id_country}`. You may pass as many HTTP parameters `?a=b&...` as you which

Comment: Ok. Then this suggestions implies that there should be only one level of depth in the url. I have read several blogs where they claim to use more, as in, customers/12/order/23/items/1. This goes against what you claim

Comment: Yeah, this really can't be answered. The data you return would be based on what the clients need. As for do `/countries/{country id}/cities/{city id}` thing, I think the point is, you should aim for short URIs, so why not just `/cities/{city id}`, allow the user to link directly to the city via a global id. There is nothing stopping this 'city' resource having a link back to the country resource that 'it resides in'.

Comment: First of all, I think you should check some existing JSON hypermedia types (HAL, JSON-LD, collection+JSON, etc... instead of creating your own one. After that you should think about what your clients need. But be aware, this can be just a default aspect of the category list. You can add further map-reduce parameters to the path or queryString: `./categories/?fields="id, name, description"`, `./categories?aspect=full`, etc...

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, really helpful